# Accidental var_dump of Eloquent ORM Connection Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm in the process of reworking the database layer of a legacy PHP application utilizing [Laravel's Eloquent ORM](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database) (and related packages).

On occasion, I will forget to call the **get** method (or other similar method which returns a collection) when working with a model. In the course of debugging, if I call var_dump on the query builder object it dumps a bunch of sensitive information such as database username / password:

```
//Trying to access User model, but forgot to use get method    
$test = User::where('name', 'Joe');

//Dump a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder object with all its sensitive bits out
var_dump($test);
```

I'm wondering if there is some safeguard that I can put in place to prevent this information from being displayed so that on the off chance that some debugging code like this gets pushed to production I don't end up offering up my db password to users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHPMD](https://phpmd.org/) with a rule like [Development Code Fragment](https://phpmd.org/rules/design.html#developmentcodefragment). You will want to run this every time before pushing up to production.

> Functions like var_dump(), print_r() etc. are normally only used
>   during development and therefore such calls in production code are a
>   good indicator that they were just forgotten.
>
> Example:

```
class SuspectCode {

    public function doSomething(array $items)
    {
        foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
            // …

            if ('qafoo' == $item) var_dump($i);

            // …
        }
    }
}
```

> This rule has the following properties:
>
> Malformed table. Text in column margin in table line 4.

```
=================================== =============== ==================================================
 Name                                Default Value   Description
=================================== =============== ==================================================
 unwanted-functions                  var_dump,print_r,debug_zval_dump,debug_print_backtrace  Comma separated list of suspect function images.
=================================== =============== ==================================================
```